# How to see that $\sin^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\le\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My calculusbook simply states that:
$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\le\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)^2$$
...but I don't immediately see why this is true.

What (probably) simple trick am I missing? Apparently it is "obvious"...

Comment: Do you know how to show that $|\sin x| < |x|$?

Comment: @ConnorHarris Well, at least I know that to be true for a fact. Can we work from there to reach the above conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By MVT

$$\sin(X)-\sin(0)=X\cos(c)$$

thus

$$|\sin(X)|\le |X|$$

and

$$\sin^2(X)\le X^2$$

now apply to
$$X=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$$

Answer (score 5):

This will follow if you show that $\sin(t) \leq t$ for all $t\geq 0$: To do that, you can try to show that if $f(0) = g(0)$ and $f'(t) \leq g'(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$, then $f(t) \leq g(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$.